# Why the movie title "The Score"?

Tags: title, the-score

I watched this movie because of the sports title "The Score". Then I got fooled and actually the movie is about a crime thriller story.

Why is the movie titled "The Score"?

Comment: I assume [this is the movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0227445/) you're talking about but it might be nice for you to clarify.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a slang expression meaning the illicit gains from a robbery...which then extended to just refer to the robbery itself.

Of course, it has a number of other meanings too.

[**Urban Dictionary**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=score&defid=1711710)

> 1. An amount due; a debt.
> 2. A grievance that is harbored and requires satisfaction
> 3. A group of 20 items.
> 4. The act of securing an advantage, especially a surprising or significant gain.
> 5. The act or an instance of buying illicit drugs.
> 6. **A successful robbery.**
> 7. A sexual conquest.